# Update multiple rows at once in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a TABLE A with the following schema :

```
|ID|   |NAME|
-------------
1        A
2        B
```

I have another table B with the following schema

```
|ID|   |STATUS|
---------------
1        4
2        5
```

I need to update the status column to 7 in table B whose ID's corresponds to the ID's in Table A.

```
Update Table B Set status = 7 where tableB.ID = tableA.id
```

How can I convert this to equivalent sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would do:

```
UPDATE B
SET status = 7
FROM TableB B
     JOIN TableA A ON B.ID = A.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi after looking at your tables the following code will perform what you want.

UPDATE B SET STATUS = 7 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM A)

Comment: @Larnu's solution, with the joins, is set based. Yours will certainly work, but it's a row-by-row operation.